# Collection Filter formula unable to use TEXT() to convert Picklist value to Text value

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, picklist, collection, text

Receiving unexpected error when debugging a subflow that uses a Collection Filter with formula referencing a picklist using TEXT().  Oddly enough, this validates successfully inside the subflow, but fails during debug and at runtime due to the following error
Field XXX is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Research confirmed this is related to a known isssue:
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwLTAA0/unable-to-use-picklist-under-formula-in-collection-filter-of-the-flow

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this workaround, but it suffices for my sake:

Create a background Formula *Text* field that converts your picklist into a Text value, then reference that value in your Collection Filter Formula.

e.g., Picklist field is `Type__c` so new formula text field "Type (Text)" set to `TEXT(Type__c)` then use this reference in your formula

```
OR(
{!currentItem_Filter_to_Filter_String.Type_text__c} = {!FilterString},
AND(
!{!TypeOnly},
CONTAINS({!currentItem_Filter_to_Filter_String.Title}, {!FilterString})
))
```